# Checkboxes Checked if in_array

Tags: php, arrays

Why does this code only check the first checkbox?

```
$activetheme = $theme->selectActiveThemeName();
foreach($blocks->availableBlockAreas($activetheme) as $block_name => $block_area_number) {
    $selected = (in_array($block_area_number, $block_areas)) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    echo '<p><input class="block_checkboxes" '. $selected .' type="checkbox" name="block_areas[]" value="'.$block_area_number.'" />'.ucfirst($block_name).'</p>';
}
```

**`$block_areas` is an array:**

```
Array ( [0] => 1,2,3 )
```

**`$blocks->availableBlockAreas($activetheme)` returns**

```
Array ( [Homepage - Left Column] => 1 [Homepage - Right Column] => 2 [Custom Page - Left Column] => 3 [Custom Page - Right Column] => 4 )
```

The `$block_area_number` should iterate?

**EDIT**:

After Geoandri' answer i came up with this fix, first i `serialized` the `array` when inserting into the `DB` then:

```
$block_areas[] = unserialize($row['block_areas']);

$selected = (in_array($block_area_number, $view->array_flatten($block_areas))) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing  $block_areas to

```
$block_areas = array(1,2,3);
```

This way I think  will work.

Comment: `$block_areas` comes from a database as 1,2,3 but can be 1,2,3,4 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc how can i change the array i have into the 1,2,3 format?

Comment: You gave me a great idea with what you said, ill add it to my question, thanks :)